# Using time.sleep(X) pauses execution

Tags: python-3.x, sleep

I tried to add some `time.sleep(.1)` to a loop I'm using, but it seems to stuck the execution (after hitting `CTRL+C` on my `IDLE` I get `time.sleep(.1)... KeyboardInterrupt` which confirms my thoughts)

I tried playing with the code, and found that adding a `print()` after that line prevents the pause, but I still don't understand why it happened in the first place...

I have no problems whatsoever running this without the `sleep`, so I think there are no other problems that can cause that. Another thing that worked for me is using `sleep(0)`. Any positive value I entered stuck the execution again.

*The suspicious line is at the end of the loop.*

This is the whole code:

```
import time 

def main():
    with open(r'txt.bin') as f:

        code = f.read()
        data = [0 for i in range(22)]
        data_p = 0
        code_p = 0
        reverse_code = code[::-1]
        l = len(code)
        flag = False

        while code[code_p] != '.':

            if data_p == 1:
                #print('char read {0}     {1}:  {2}'.format(c, data_p,data[1]))
                pass

            c = code[code_p]
            if c == '+':
                data[data_p] += 1
                data[data_p] %= 256
            elif c == '-':
                data[data_p] -= 1
                if data[data_p] < 0:
                    data[data_p] = 255
            elif c == '>':
                data_p += 1
            elif c == '<':
                data_p -= 1
            elif c == ',':
                old = int(data[data_p])
                data[data_p] = int(input('enter value at {0} (current value is {1}):    '.format(data_p, data[data_p])))
                print('replaced {0} with {1} at {2}'.format(old, data[data_p],data_p))
                flag = True
            elif c == '[':
                if data[data_p] is 0:
                    old = int(code_p)
                    code_p = code.find(']', code_p)
                    print('started at loc {0} with val {1}\nnow at loc {2} with val {3}'.format(old, code[old], code_p, code[code_p]))
            elif c == ']':
                if data[data_p] is not 0:
                    reverse_code_p = l-1-code_p
                    old = int(code_p)
                    code_p = l-1-reverse_code.find('[', reverse_code_p)
                    print('started at loc {0} with val {1}\nnow at loc {2} with val {3}'.format(old, code[old], code_p, code[code_p]))

            if flag:
                time.sleep(1)


            code_p += 1

        print(data[data_p])
main()
```

Comment: If something is getting executed after time.sleep(), that means it is not getting stuck..

Comment: @AakashVerma read again. If I enter positive values nothing is executed after sleep and I have to stop execution with CTRL+C

Comment: Unrelated to your question: Do not compare for equality be comparing for identity. That is `elif c is ']'` or `code[code_p] is not '.'`; use `elif c == ']` and `!= '.'` instead. Your code currently "just happens to work" due to the happenstance of CPython interning common integers and things that look like labels. Execution on PyPy and other interpreters will go wrong, as will slight changes to your code. Observe that `-5 is -5` is true in python2, python3, pypy2 and pypy3 while `-6 is -6` is true in python2, pypy2 and pypy3 but false in python3

Comment: @user2722968 thx! I'll change my code

Comment: What does it do if you `raise SystemError` after the sleep?

Comment: I get "  File "C:/....py", line 51, in main
    raise SystemError
SystemError" which makes me think the code isn't stuck after all. But if so, why the loop isn't continuing?

Comment: I suspect it's some weird interaction with Idle. Did you run it in console?

Comment: @user2722968 Yup. Same results on console

Comment: Then your code is simply stuck in a large loop that sleeps for most of it's time. If you replace the sleep with a `print "I'm sleeping"` you'll probably see lots and lots of those lines.